# how to move files one by one and rename it from a directory to another in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rename, move

To those who are knowledgeable here in vb.net please help me.

i have to make a program that move images (in jpg) from a directory to another but before that it will first rename a file before moving it into the destination folder. i need it like this because each time it renames a file it'll save into the database (mysql)

i have already a program that moves all jpg files into another directory but that's not what i need.

please i need you're expertise and the codes.

i'm not that good in vb.net

---

The OP's move method from the comments:

```
Dim sourceDirectory As String = TextBox1.Text 
Dim archiveDirectory As String = TextBox2.Text 
Try 
    Dim jpgFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.jpg") 
    For Each currentFile As String In jpgFiles 
        Dim fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1) 
        Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName)) 
    Next 
Catch e As Exception 
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message) 
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`System.IO.File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) you have the option to rename the file at the same time as you move it. I am not sure how you are determining what the new file name is to be, so the best I can suggest is to look at the example code in the MSDN link that I gave.

From Above Link:

> Moves a specified file to a new location, providing the option to specify a new file name.

```
File.Move ( sourceFileName As String, destFileName As String )
```

---

Added example based on OP's comment showing how to rename the file:

```
Dim sourceDirectory As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim archiveDirectory As String = TextBox2.Text
Try
    Dim jpgFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.jpg")
    For Each currentFile As String In jpgFiles
        Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(currentFile)
        Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) & ".old"))
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Dim sourceDirectory As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = TextBox2.Text

        Try
            Dim jpgFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.jpg")

            For Each currentFile As String In jpgFiles
                Dim fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
                Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
            Next
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try  this is my code of moving files i've just found it on MSDN samples too. pls help

Comment: Any of the move commands will give you the option of renaming the file at the time that you move it. The destination filename does not need to be the same as the source. I will put an example that changes the file extension. still am not sure how/what your renaming scheme is.

Comment: Also please do not dump code in the comments, it is very messy and hard to read. You can always edit your question to add your code and then leave a comment to direct our attention to your changes.

Comment: oh sorry mark :) i'm just a newbie here.. next time i'll do as you've told me :) thank you.. :) now it's clear to me.. :)

Comment: can i ask a question? how come i can't marked both of your answers of akhil as marked?

Comment: You can only have one accepted answer, that would be the one that helped you the most, when you get to reputation of 15 you can uptick the answer that would give them 10 pts of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

since you have code for moving file to folder,i will suggest rename function for renaming the files you have moved.

```
Rename(Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & oldname.Text & "", Application.StartupPath & "\Images\" & newname.Text & "")
```

and just for your knowledge function to copy files from one directory to another(instead of moving)

```
FileCopy(sourcefilename, destinationfilename)
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Dim sourceDirectory As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = TextBox2.Text

        Try
            Dim jpgFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.jpg")

            For Each currentFile As String In jpgFiles
                Dim fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
                Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
            Next
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try   that is my code of moving files but where would i put the codes for renaming it?

Comment: put the code for renaming after Directory.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName)) part of your code.it should work.also as the comments seen above move commands give options to rename the files simultaneous with the move.try those methods too.

Comment: thank you akhil :) both of you and mark gave me a clearer vision of what to do :)